# How to make your bot user reply with a simple help message using slack bot

Tags: slack-api

I have created a `slack bot` and I want to send a general static help message to users when they send a direct message to my bot:

[image: slack help message to DM]

Should I subscribe to `Events API`? Or do I need to do this in another way? I couldn't find a clear answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do make your [bot user](https://api.slack.com/bot-users) reply to direct messages:

- [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api)
- [Real Time Messaging API](https://api.slack.com/rtm)

In my opinion the Events API approach is easier to implement since it does not require using [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

The basic approach with the Events API is:

- You need an endpoint that can receive [event requests](https://api.slack.com/events-api#receiving_events) from Slack and
  react to it, e.g. by sending a direct message back to a user.
- Subscribe to [`message.im`](https://api.slack.com/events/message.im) event for your bot user

Note that a bot user already has all the required scopes for this with the [`bot`](https://api.slack.com/scopes/bot) scope.

In addition I would recommend to subscribe to [`app.mention`](https://api.slack.com/events/app_mention) for your bot user. Then it can also react to mentions in other channels.

Btw. that message you posted looks a lot like a review comment from the Slack team for a new app submission. I got a similar one for my last app and I solved it with the approach above. In general it looks like if you want to have a bot user in your app it needs to be able to respond to help request from users.